# How to do a custom sort for pandas series

Tags: pandas, sorting, series

I have a column in a dataframe called sentiment that has three categories, pos, neg, and neu. I want to call `movie_df['sentiment'].sort_values(by=['neg', 'neu', 'pos'])` so that they appear in that order in my histogram, but you can't use by= with a Series. It looks like you can only do custom sorting with a dataframe but when I try

```
frame = movie_df['sentiment'].sort_values(by=['neg', 'neu', 'pos'])
```

this gives me this error: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by'

How can I apply this custom sort?

Comment: `movie_df['sentiment'] = pd.Categorical(movie_df['sentiment'], categories=['neg', 'neu', 'pos'],ordered=True)` , then your plot should be in order `['neg', 'neu', 'pos']` , or you can then do `movie_df['sentiment'] .sort_values()` to see it in the data

Comment: Also, regarding your error please note that `movie_df['sentiment']` is a `Series` object; `Series.sort_values()` does not have a `by` parameter.